# Secure cookies and TLS termination in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: session-cookies, azure-application-gateway

A requirement for my application is that its cookies are served over HTTPS only (Secure attribute). It is also to be hosted behind Azure Application Gateway with TLS termination configured: the client-to-gateway connection is secure, the gateway-to-backend connection is not.

This causes Secure cookies to be refused by the application since its connection is insecure:

> The application is configured to issue secure cookies. These cookies require the browser to issue the request over SSL (https protocol). However, the current request is not over SSL.

How can I configure either:

- The application to accept secure cookies over an insecure connection
  or
- The Application Gateway to pass cookies as non-Secure to the backend?

There seem to be no other questions on SO about this specifically for Azure App Gateway, and Microsoft's documentation never mentions anything about cookie security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of my problem is that my .NET 6 application refuses the cookie when sent by the client.
It turns out there is a built-in middleware specifically to ensure compatibility with load balancers [as described in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0): [ForwardedHeaders](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/ForwardedHeadersExtensions.cs)

The original connection scheme is sent in the header `X-Forwarded-Proto` and the ForwarderHeaders middleware can use this to internally consider the connection secure.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are either sent to a server, or they aren't; nothing security related is transmitted except for the initial issuance of the cookie.  The client will determine whether or not to do this based on how the cookie was issued by the `Secure` flag set in the initial `Set-Cookie` header, and even then this is still a client's decision.  What you have in addition to this however, is that your application is expecting to receive this cookie on HTTPS only, explicitly rejecting it if it's received on plaintext HTTP.

The Application Gateway is already passing the cookie as "non-secure", because of the fact that it's doing so over HTTP and the `Cookie` header does not contain any flags; just the keys and values.  You would either have to change the backend application to accept this cookie over HTTP, or connect the Application Gateway to the backend over HTTPS which goes against your requirements.  Application Gateway's only relevance to cookies is related to Affinity Cookies, and header rewrites (inadvisable), which is why there isn't any documentation specific to cookie security as it is unimportant to the Application Gateway's role in proxying the traffic.

Comment: As an aside, because I'm sure someone will ask: header rewrites against cookies are inadvisable for Application Gateway because multiple cookies are set in a single response with multiple `Set-Cookie` headers.  A header rewrite will replace all of these headers with a single one, not each with a desired rewritten value.

Comment: In practice it turns out it's quite possible to define cookies as secure on a non-https backend. The connection between the user and the app gateway is always HTTPS, so the browser will set the cookies, but when it transmits them back, they are refused by the backend because the backend is non-https.

Comment: I see your point about the App Gateway having nothing to do with cookies, but the App Gateway is the only part of the chain where this can be resolved. I agree that header rewrites are not the solution here.
I was hoping there would be something like 'TLS termination for cookies' because they are an integral part of the HTTP message that the App Gateway transmits.

Comment: Nice to see you had that flexibility to base the incoming protocol on the XFP header.  Very similar to grabbing client IP from the XFF header when the proxy is rewriting the source IP to its own.